# Generate code coverage report using Firebase testLab. Get one report instead of multiple .ec files

Tags: firebase, code-coverage, gcloud, test-coverage, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to generate a code coverage report using firebase testLab. Below is the command i ran in gCloud. All tests passed and I have several .ec files generated.One for each test, but I do not see a report. Can any one tell me what I might be doing wrong? what can I do to get the report?

1. I want to consolidated report with code coverage.
2. unable to open .ec file

   gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation --app  --test --device model=blueline,version=28,locale=en,orientation=portrait
   --environment-variables USERNAME=,PASSWORD=,coverage=true,coverageFilePath="/sdcard/coverage.ec"
   --directories-to-pull /sdcard --use-orchestrator --test-targets=

[image]

Jacoco task:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTree])
    executionData.from = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Test Lab doesn't generate coverage reports directly. For that, you need to use a tool like `jacoco` to parse your `.ec` files.  This [blog](https://medium.com/mobile-testing/combining-code-coverage-reports-from-ftl-and-unit-tests-9c795ea269da) gives an example of doing that.

Comment: Hi Davis, Thank you, but the article is not clear on where I run the command. Can you help me on where I should run the gsutil command? Also I have a jacoco task (added the code in the question above). Should I add a new one or add to this?